# How to implement XMPP protocol in objective-C?

Tags: iphone, chat, xmpp

How to implement XMPP protocol in objective-C?

I want to send & receive messages from Jabber server through XMPP.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: //*****Best Way create podfile with This info:

platform :ios, '8.0'

use_frameworks!

pod 'XMPPFramework', :git => "https://github.com/robbiehanson/XMPPFramework.git", :branch => 'master'

pod 'CocoaAsyncSocket'

pod 'CocoaLumberjack/Swift'

pod 'KissXML/SwiftNSXML'

Answer (score 13):

Make use of the [XMPP Framework for Cocoa](https://github.com/robbiehanson/XMPPFramework).

Here's the [Getting started using XMPPFramework on iOS](https://github.com/robbiehanson/XMPPFramework/wiki/GettingStarted_iOS).

Comment: Thanks. But available source code is for MAC. not for iOS

Comment: @Dilip look closer: there's an example project under `Xcode/iPhoneXMPP/`

Comment: @Nick.... Thanks. :) I'll go through it.

Comment: @Nick....thanks so much..I done with recieving msgs...but how to send msg to jabber.. Thanks so much for your effort.

Comment: @Nick: Above links are not working... Can you please post new links? Thanks

Comment: @iOSAppDev should work again.

Answer (score 3):

This is a good tutorial about setting up Jabber client and and will help you to use xmpp.

http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/building-a-jabber-client-for-ios-interface-setup/