# How will create chat using xmpp in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, xmpp

How to implement `XMPP` protocol in objective-C?

I want to send & receive messages from Jabber server through `XMPP`.

I will check chat secure https://github.com/ChatSecure/ChatSecure-iOS.
 But i have some file missing.

Comment: similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6358244/how-to-implement-xmpp-protocol-in-objective-c

Comment: use Openfire server cool and easy,

Comment: Thank ur answering .But some files are missing

Comment: Are you using `CocoaPods` for the library?

Comment: yes.its have cocoa pods